# Symfony php unit test using mock object in form and controler

Tags: symfony

Hi Guyz i was having a hard time in php unit test can any of you can create a form and a unit test same as the controller it will be a great help for me as a student we are studying framework and symfony2 is one of them, php unit test is one of the feature so we need to know about it i hope some one can help me don't suggest any link to read cause i am tired of reading need a simple example using mock object.

i created a simple form in symfony 2 can any of you create a phpunit test for this, using mock object.

```
<?php
namespace App\MainBundle\Form\Exercises;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class TennisType extends AbstractType
{
     /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
         $builder
            ->add('sets',  'text',['attr'=>['maxlength'=>'3', 'size'=>'3'],'required' => false,])
            ->add('duration',  'text', ['attr'=> ['maxlength'=>'3', 'size'=>'3'],'required' => True,])
            ->add('intensity',  'choice', ['choices'=> ['low'=>'low', 'medium'=>'medium', 'high'=>'high', 'intense'=>'intense'],'required' => True,])
            ->add('unit',  'choice', ['choices'=> ['hour'=>'hour', 'min'=>'min'],'required' => True,])
            ->add('field', new ExerciseLogType())
            ;
    }


    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'App\MainBundle\Entity\Exercises\ExerciseLog'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tennis_exerciselog';
    }
}
```

Comment: i created a simple code for the form can you make me a unit test for this, using mock object

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for a simple form submit test. You can use a alert tooltip for notice that create is OK or not and crawler for get response form submit.

```
$client = static::makeClient());

$crawler = $client->request('GET', self::ROUTE);

$form = $crawler->selectButton('Acme_mainbundle_produit[submit]')->form();
$form['Acme_mainbundle_produit[name]'] = 'PRODUIT TEST CREATE';

$client->submit($form);

$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect(self::ROUTE));

$crawler = $client->followRedirect();

$this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('.alert.alert-success')->count() == 1);
```

Comment: thank you for this but this is not what i am looking for this is, test for form submit but this is a high level for me so i add a simple program in my question